# Getting type from template value, C++

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-variant

I have the following method in which I'm using boost::variant. I try to get the value, based on type `T`. If `boost::get<T>` fails I want to handle that in a special way if T is an int or unsigned int. Is there any way to know if `T` is an int or unsigned int?

I don't think I can use template specialization in this case, can I?

EDIT: Also, I don't yet have access to C++11 (soon I hope)

```
template < typename T, typename C, void (C::*setterFcn)(const T&) >
void binder( const Variant& value_var, C* c )
{
    const T* typeData = boost::get<T>(&value_var);

    if ( NULL == typeData )
    {
        // Need to check for int or unsigned int here somehow
    }

    (((C*) c)->*(setterFcn))(*typeData);
}
```

Comment: Something like `std::is_same<T, int>::value`? Or just specialize the whole thing for `int`.

Comment: I don't believe I can do partial template specialization for this, can I?

Comment: @NicFoster : No, since one cannot partially specialize a function template. However, you could accomplish this easily with _overloading_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11 you can use [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) and in C++03 you can do something like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class is_same
{
public: 
    static bool const value = false;
};

template <typename T>
class is_same<T, T>
{
public: 
    static bool const value = true;
};
```

and use it exactly as C++11 standard version.

Comment: Griwes, thanks for the edit. I just went to the docs and wanted to update to exactly what you proposed. This way transition to C++11 would be painless.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use is_same() on boost or on C++11.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to just delegate to overloaded functions or function templates: You specify the general handling, possibly doing nothing, in one function and the specialized handling either in two separate functions (if the extra handling is trivial) or in an `enable_if`ed function with the condition checking for `int` or `unsigned int`.